# Unable to run the test in python due to module not found error

Tags: python

`ModuleNotFoundError` when running the test. Following is the project structure I have.

```
 src
└  he
  │  __init__.py
  └  sample.py
 tests
│  __init__.py
└  test_something.py
 requirements.txt
```

#### sample.py

```py
def print_something():
    print('hello world')
```

#### test_something.py

```py
import unittest
from he.sample import print_something

class SomethingTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_something(self):
        print_something()

if __name__ == '__main__ ':
    unittest.main()
```

But, when running the test, `python tests/test_something.py` I get following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/s1n7ax/workspace/sample/tests/test_something.py", line 2, in <module>
    from he.sample import print_something
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'he'
```

#### I tried 1

I tried changing the folder structure without `src`. Still test didn't work. How to run the test?

```
 he
│  __init__.py
└  sample.py
 tests
│  __init__.py
└  test_something.py
 requirements.txt
```

Python version: Python 3.9.2.

#### I tried 2

Since I'm using Linux, I make sure the permission are correct.

```
chown -R s1n7ax:s1n7ax sample_project
chmod -R a+r sample_project
chmod -R a+x sample_project
```

Comment: I hope you get a good answer, as I am also frequently getting this kind of issues with modules. I typically randomly try relative imports until it somehow works. E.g. `from ..src.he import sample`, `from ..he import sample`, ...

Comment: The main confusion is that you need a `.` if you have a `__init__.py` and don't if you don't

Comment: @mousetail what?

Comment: Sorry, I was replying to user_na. Basically the reason the syntax is sometimes different is because it depends on where `__init__.py` files are or aren't

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by adding `__init__.py` to the `src` folder:

```
 src
└  he
  │  __init__.py
  └  sample.py
└  __init__.py
 tests
│  __init__.py
└  test_something.py
 requirements.txt
```

In your `test_something.py`:

```
from ..src.he import sample
```

Or, for the second layout, use the import syntax like this:

```
from ..he import sample
```